# Find area of this bounded curve. I don't know how to start? This question was asked in Mathematical belarusian olympiad.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area, curves

> Find the area bounded by the curve:
> $$\left(\frac x2 + \frac y3\right)^4= 4xy$$

Tried using subtitutions but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I agree that you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem but in order to maintain this site as a repository of quality mathematical knowledge you should read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You could begin by showing *which* substitutions you have tried...

Comment: SarGe i get what you are saying you want me to post my work but i couldn't think of anything. See its graph on desmos. I can't think of solving this by integration.

Comment: Aryan i tried like x=2sin²(q) and  y=3cos²(q) to avoid the power 4 but it didn't work.

Comment: Make the Change of Variables $X=x/2, Y=y/3$, your equation becomes $(X+Y)^4=24XY$ which is the equation of a curve symmetrical with respect to line $Y=X$. If you find the area enclosed, it remains (due to the Ch. Of Var.) to multiply the result by $2 \times 3=6$

Comment: Finding the area enclosed is the real problem.

Comment: @Obsessed with integrals: please include your attempts by adding them in the body of the post. Also, with your current substitution, you have limited the values of $x$ to $[0,2]$ and $y$ to $[0,3]$, which is not the case.

Comment: True aryan thats why i asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the change of variable:

$$X=x/2,Y=y/3. \tag{1}$$

the initial equation becomes :

$$(X+Y)^4=24XY \tag{2}$$

Let us compute the area $S$ enclosed by curve $(C)$ defined by equation (2), knowing that finally, when returning to the original variables, you will have to multiply $S$ by $2 \times 3 = 6$.

Some remarks about curve $(C)$ : it is in particular symmetrical with respect to the origin because (2) is invariant by transformation $(X,Y) \to (-X,-Y)$ ; furthermore, $(C)$ is not situated in quadrants II and IV (it is impossible for example that $X<0$ and $Y>0$ simultaneously).

[image]

Set $$Y=aX \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ a>0\tag{4}$$

in equation (2) (it amounts to look for the intersection of the curve with straight line having equation (4)).

You will obtain

$$X=\frac{\sqrt{24a}}{(1+a)^2}. \tag{5}$$

As a consequence,

$$Y=aX=a\frac{\sqrt{24a}}{(1+a)^2}\tag{6}.$$

With (5) and (6) we have a parametric representation of curve $(C)$.

Then apply formula for the area of a parametric curve:

$$S=\int_{a=0}^{a=\infty}\frac12(XdY-YdX)$$
for the area of one loop.

Multiply this result by $2$ to account for the second loop, in quadrant III. And don't forget to multiply the result by $6$ as said upwards.

**Remark:** curve $(C)$ is a [**lemniscate of Gerono**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono), not to be confused with a lemniscate of Bernoulli.

It can be shown by using a $\pi/4$ coordinates rotation

$$\begin{cases}X+Y&=&\sqrt{2}u\\X-Y&=&\sqrt{2}v\end{cases}$$

transform (2) into the following equation in variables $u,v$:

$$u^4=3(u^2-v^2)$$

which is one of the forms of the equation of such a lemniscate (see [this site](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/gerono/gerono.shtml)).

Comment: Yeah both of your approach worked and ans is 24 and its correct thankyou. What i did was mixed both of your approach first i changed the basis or variable as suggested by jean and then converted it into parametrics form as X=rsint and Y=rcost and solved for r²= 12sin2t/(sint+cost)⁴ and then applied polar integration form from 0 to pi/2 and multiplied by 2 as there are two loops and then multiplied by 6 as we changed variable basis. And i got the answer.

Comment: I have added some more information to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using GeoGebra, the graph happens to have two loops; one in the first quadrant and the other in the third quadrant.

Substitute :
$$x=2r\cos^2a ,  y=3r\sin^2a$$
On simplifying, we get:
$$r^2=6\sin^2(2a)$$

Now consider a sector of angle $da$ making an angle $a$ with $X$ axis.

The area of sector is
$$\frac 12 r^2da$$
Therefore, the area of the loop in first quadrant is
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac12r^2da$$

Now, the area of both the loops will be twice this integral.

Substituting the value of $r^2$ in the given integral, the area can be found.

Comment: Firstly on calculations using your substitution , r² would be 6sin²(2a) and second how can we calculate area with this i dont understand. Please explain.

Comment: here r is the distance from origin to any point on curve so if we consider a small sector of radius r fom origin to the curve , the area of the loop will be the sum of all the very small sectors.

Comment: if you want to understand this better here is a similar problem https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-area-bounded-by-the-curve-x-4-y-4-2xy