# Name of the family of curves

Tags: terminology, curves

I tried to generalize the [Lemniscate of Gerono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono).

Instead of $x = \dfrac{t^{2} - 1}{t^{2}+1}$ and $y = \dfrac{2t(t^{2}-1)}{(t^{2} - 1)^{2}}$, I used $x = \dfrac{a(t^{2} - 1)}{t^{2}+1}$ and $y = \dfrac{bt(t^{2}-1)}{(t^{2} - 1)^{2}}$.

When eliminating $t$, I used the positive root instead of both. What I got is this:

$y = \dfrac{bx}{a}\left(\dfrac{a - x}{2a}\right)\sqrt{\dfrac{a + x}{a - x}}$

Out of curiosity, I replaced $y$ by $y^{2}$. Can I ask what is the name of the family of the curve
$y^{2} = \dfrac{bx}{a}\left(\dfrac{a - x}{2a}\right)\sqrt{\dfrac{a + x}{a - x}}$?

Comment: Let me propose *kevs924 curves*. They are nice. $\to +1$.

Comment: It is more than likely that this modified curve does not have a name because it does not have a geometric construction as sound as that of Gerono's. Replacing $y$ by $y^2$ makes a nonlinear deformation of the plane which can be called an anamorphosis, obtained with a special cylindrical mirror.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I propose "bow tie lemniscate" (see my answer)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the equation of your curve can be simplified into:

$y^{2} = \dfrac{bx}{2a^2}\sqrt{(a + x)(a - x)}\tag{1}$

with the very tiny difference that here $x \in [0,a]$ whereas in the initial version, $x \in [0,a)$.

This type of curves belong to the general family of **quartics** **like other lemniscates** because when both sides of (1) are squared, equation:

$y^{4} = \dfrac{b^2x^2}{4a^4}(a^2 - x^2)\tag{2}$

is the zero set of a 4th degree polynomial.

The curve with equation (1) hasn't the shape of an $\infty$, therefore cannot be called a generalized lemniscate, because $x$ cannot take negative values.

Whereas, with equation (2), you would get a "bow-tie" lemniscate (the same curve with its symmetrical part with respect to the ordinate axis)

[image]

*Fig. 1: The "bow-tie" lemniscate. In blue: curve with equation (1) (case $a=5, \ b=3$). In red+blue: curve with equation (2).*

Besides, here are two pieces of information that can have their interest in your attempt to find other types of curves with the $\infty$ shape:

1. Are you aware that the lemniscate of Gerono can be considered as the projection of Viviani's curve (see corresponding Wikipedia article), which is the intersection of a sphere centered in $O$ with **radius** $OA=R$ and a cylinder with **diameter** $OA$ ? Therefore your research could be oriented towards a definition taking into account a generalization of the sphere and/or a generalization of the cylinder.
2. In a recent answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770880), I have had the opportunity to work on a $\pi/4$ rotated version of Gerono's lemniscate. It could be beneficial to your extension to attempt this kind of transformation.

Web references: [Lemniscate of Gerono - Mathcurve](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/gerono/gerono.shtml) and [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6937021_Insect-like_flapping_wing_mechanism_based_on_a_double_spherical_Scotch_yoke/) showing the connection with Bernoulli's lemniscate, somewhat the "archetype" of all lemniscates.

Comment: I am sorry if I used the term "generalize". I am just looking for a particular curve.

Comment: I fully agree. Very nice ! And guess what ? ..... $\to +1$ . As Snoopy, are you happy of this enormous gift from a friend ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thanks. A direct filiation, Bernoulli, Viviani, Snoopi :). By the way, I was just enjoying reading  this nice document about Viviani : http://www.mathouriste.eu/Viviani/Viviani.html about Viviani, Bernoulli and co.

Comment: I am sorry if the reason behind is not clear. At first, I tried to "generalize" the curve, but my curious mind made me replace $y$ by $y^{2}$. So now, it is not the lemniscate that I was talking about, but the equation I just derived.

Comment: Don't be sorry for that! Your intuition wasn't bad: the resulting curve is interesting... In fact, its general shape is still that of a lemnicate...